# How to reference an existing chart in a google spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script

I want to make changes to existing google charts in my spreadsheet when new data is entered. I have and onEdit function that is working nicely but I cannot figure out how to get a "pointer" to the existing chart objects in the spreadsheet.

Answer (score 1):

See [Programmatically Managing Charts in Spreadsheets](http://googleappsdeveloper.blogspot.fr/2012/06/programmatically-managing-charts-in.html):

Also, [Other Google I/O announcements](http://googleappsdeveloper.blogspot.fr/2012/06/big-updates-for-apps-script.html) may be of interest

Answer (score 0):

I hate to have to break the bad news. But it is just not possible. There's no API at all to deal with charts in spreadsheets.

If it's not a problem in your use-case. You could generate the chart image/url automatically from the script using the [Google Charts Tools](https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/index) and then insert the it on the spreadsheet.